# Time format when adding hours in Quip

Tags: formulas, quip

After some deep research, I've been looking for a way to sum/subtract hours in [Quip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quip_(software)) Spreadsheet (Salesforce subsidiary).
Apparently, time formats such as `25:00:00` are not listed in their menu `Format > Number > More Formats...` and I couldn't find any function to help me to convert it directly.

If you sum 15:30 (15 hours and 30 minutes, not the proper hour) and 12:45, it will result 4:15, but the desired result is 28:15 (28 hours and 15 minutes). Am I missing any documentation which can help me or is there any workaround which can solve it? Is this feature included in Quip?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to sum/subtract hours by using the [TIME](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.quip_supported_formulas_and_functions.htm&type=5) function and adding that to the desired column to modify.

Example:

If B3 is 9:00

and B4 is

> =B3-TIME(1, 0, 0)

B4 will result in 8:00. 10:00, if adding instead of subtracting.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for something similar and ended up entering the values in minutes and then adding them up in a cell and dividing by 60, like =SUM(R11:V11)/60